# Script to fill a web form using a set of data

Tags: javascript, python

I am currently configuring software, however, the fields I am configuring requires a very simple set of data (3 variable fileds) to be entered into a form. However, this operation needs to be done approximately 2,500 times to cover all cases. I can easily genrate a csv containing all the fields for all the entries of this tabel.

I am looking for high level information as to how this can best be accomplished using a script. Could somebody provide a crash course on how to incorperate a custom script to load and submit this information using an external file. Things such as: what fields should I look for using the inspect element or how to load and iterate through a file using JS or python, etc.  Or provide any resources that would be helpful on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you want a method to read csv file containing a very simple set of data (3 variable fields), and output those fields to your application?

Comment: @MatrixTai Yes. But the application is a rather simple web form. Also if it is relevant, the fields are drop down menus, however, they allow text entry

Comment: If it is web application, you need to be clear about where your csv file is? Server or local? You want to upload the csv from local to your web application through http? Or are you asking how the backend (using JS/PY) read the csv file already on server?

Comment: @MatrixTai Sorry about that. The CSV is local on my machine. I would like to use a script to populate the fields and submit the form, all within google chrome. Something like `Open field 1> populateField1FromFile(i) > Open field 2 > populateField2FromFile(i) > .... > submit form > i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I suggest using python rather than javascript, which can be executed conveniently in local.

At the beginning, you need a I/O. In case you are not familiar, take a look on [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/reading-csv-files-python-3/).

Next, you need a way to send http request. The library for this is [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), which is inbuilt. Then you need a way to make everything in json, which is well-accepted type for data transferring through http.

You can find the sample of using urllib [here](https://intelligea.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/get-and-post-in-python-with-urllib-urllib2-quick-example/).
Please remember that you are 'passing the data', use 'POST' method instead of 'GET' method.

Your data should be encoded in

```
from json import dumps
data= dumps({
    //data dictionary
})    
...
urllib.urlencode({'login' : 'MyLogin', 'password' : 'MyPassword', 'data': data})
```

You can ignore login and password just in case your backend doesn't require verification.
Welcome to ask me if you have any problem about this.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, hope still help.